# how to access class method from instance method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-5

I have model:

```
class UserWeight < ActiveRecord::Base

  self.table_name = 'Weight'

  scope :logged_between, lambda { |start_date, end_date|
    where(weight_date: start_date.to_date...(end_date.to_date.end_of_day)) unless
    start_date.nil? || end_date.nil?
  }

  # returns the sum of points 
  def total_points
      self.class.Userweight
    (UserWeight.blank?) ? 0 : UserWeight.inject(0) {|a, e| a + e.points}
  end
end
```

Controller:

```
@weights = weight_usages.logged_between(params[:start_date], end_date)
```

I get following data in weights:

```
weights: [
{
weight: "170.0",
weight_date: "2016-12-28",
points: 1
},
{
weight: "185.0",
weight_date: "2017-01-04",
points: 1
}
.......
 ]
```

Active record is returning collection of arrays. I want to access class method and do the sum in the instance method. based on the data i want to return total points 2 from instance method. Any idea how can i do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method looks to make little to no sense, because `total_points` is an instance method, so why would you want to present the all records `points`'s sum in an *instance method*?

Beside the above note, use ActiveRecord's methods. You are looking for [`sum`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Calculations.html#method-i-sum):

```
UserWeight.sum(:points)
```

In method:

```
self.class.sum(:points)
```

Comment: Thanks Andrey for your response. I am just trying to understand the concept. I edited question for the data i am getting in array. when i do self.class.sum(:points) in method i am getting much bigger number. based on data i should get 2.

Comment: @User4432432432 to see what you have in records, do `UserWeight.pluck(:points)` - this will produce an array of points

Comment: when i do that i get [nil, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, nil, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1] and it does add to 23 but on application it shows me 2 Weights arrays with points = 1 and 4 with 0. so did not understand why its returning 23.

Comment: @User4432432432 in application (in controller) you are filtering it by means of scope `logged_between`. ***THUS***: call the `sum(:points)` on `weight_usages.logged_between(params[:start_date], end_date)`: `weight_usages.logged_between(params[:start_date], end_date).sum(:points)`